# CSV to dict, dict not finding the item

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am converting a CSV to `dict`, all the values are loaded correctly but with one issue.

CSV :

```
Testing    testing\nwe are into testing mode
My\nServer This is my server.
```

When I convert the CSV to dict and if I try to use `dict.get()` method it is returning `None`.

When I debug, I get the following output:

```
{'Testing': 'testing\\nwe are into testing mode', 'My\\nServer': 'This is my server.'}
```

The **My\nServer** key is having an extra backslash.

If I do `.get("My\nServer")`, I am getting the output as `None`.

Can anyone help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import codecs
import json
from csv import reader

def get_dict(path):
    with codecs.open(path, 'r', 'utf-8') as msgfile:
        data = msgfile.read()
        data = reader([r.encode('utf-8') for r in data.splitlines()])
        newdata = []
        for row in data:
            newrow = []
            for val in row:
                newrow.append(unicode(val, 'utf-8'))
            newdata.append(newrow)
    return dict(newdata)
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to escape the newline properly, using `\\n`:

```
>>> d = {'Testing': 'testing\\nwe are into testing mode', 'My\\nServer': 'This is my server.'}
>>> d.get('My\\nServer')
'This is my server.'
```

or you can use a [raw string literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) which doesn't need extra escaping:

```
>>> d.get(r'My\nServer')
'This is my server.'
```

Note that raw string will treat all the backslash escape sequences this way, not just the newline `\n`.

In case you are getting the values dynamically, you can use [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) with [`string_escape` or `unicode_escape` encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
>>> k = 'My\nServer' # API call result
>>> k.encode('string_escape')
'My\\nServer'
>>> d.get(k.encode('string_escape'))
'This is my server.'
```

Comment: yes, when converting from CSV to DICT, i dont want to an extra backslash.

Comment: @SyedAbdulQadeer Ah, I see, added another option for that.

Comment: that is working absolutely fine, just one more question , please consider that i am getting that 'My\nServer' from an API call, so i store the string in a variable myVar; so myVar = someApiCall() , and if i use d.get(myVar) , it doesn't seems to be working, can you help me with typecasting the variable to Raw String Literal ?

Comment: @SyedAbdulQadeer Added information on how to do this dynamically using string encodings.

Answer (score 0):

`"\n"` is newline.

If you want to represent a text like `"---\n---"` in Python, and not having there newline, you have to escape it.

The way you write it in code and how it gets printed differs, in code, you will have to write "\" (unless u use raw string), when printed, the extra slash will not be seen

So in your code, you shall ask:

```
>>> dct = {'Testing': 'testing\\nwe are into testing mode', 'My\\nServer': 'This is my server.'}
>>> dct.get("My\\nServer")
'This is my server.'
```

Comment: Hello Jan, please consider this scenario : i am accessing an open API, and the API returns me the string "My\nServer", now i can look this string in the CSV file and display my own text. since i have no control over what is being returned from the API. so i created this method to build the dict from CSV so that i can pass the string and get my desired string, please note that i cant go and change all 5000+ strings in the csv and add one extra backslash